# Procedure or function 'stored_pr' expects parameter '@name', which was not supplied

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I try to make a simpe app with asp and I have a problem.

> Procedure or function 'stored_pr' expects parameter '@name', which was
>   not supplied.

My Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[spq]
@name nvarchar(max)
as
insert into tableq (name)
Values 
(@name)
GO
```

My code in ASP:

```
    using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlConnection con;
    //Here we declare the parameter which we have to use in our application
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlParameter @name = new SqlParameter();


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        con = new SqlConnection("server=(local); database=**;uid=DefaultAppPool;pwd=*****");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ((TextBox)this.Page.FindControl("Pole")).Text;

        cmd = new SqlCommand("spq", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

and

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

<asp:TextBox ID="Pole" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit Record" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please any help..
thank you

Comment: As the parameter is of type `nvarchar`, you might need SqlDbType.NVarChar` to properly set it's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem more than likely lies in these 2 lines, although there might be other issues in the code:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ((TextBox)this.Page.FindControl("Pole")).Text;

cmd = new SqlCommand("spq", con);
```

You're basically adding a parameter to the command and then effectively clearing it by newing it up again. Swap the 2 lines around and you should get past that error.

Take a look at the documentation for a sample:

[**MSDN: SqlCommand.Parameters Property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Bug! Swap these two lines:

```
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ((TextBox)this.Page.FindControl("Pole")).Text;

    cmd = new SqlCommand("spq", con);
```